# How do I print to the screen what the user types in a text box in html?

Tags: html

I am looking to print out what the user types

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <h3>- Students Name & Age -</h3>
   <input id="d1">
   <button class="button" onclick="addName()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Without using javascript?

Comment: With using javascript I am assuming there is not another way

Comment: Have you made any attempts to make this happen? Can you show your code, and explain what went wrong?

Comment: Have you attempted to write the `addName` function yet? Can we see what you've tried?

Comment: function addName() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('d1').get)
    }

Comment: console.log only for now. My ultimate goal is to print some sort of label of the student information on the actual webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function addName() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('d1').value;
  document.getElementById("name").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <h3>- Students Name & Age -</h3>
  <input id="d1">
  <button class="button" onclick="addName()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

```js
var addName = function() {
   alert(document.getElementById('d1').value);
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <h3>- Students Name & Age -</h3>
   <input id="d1">
   <button class="button" onclick="addName()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Lets say the user types "hello" into the text box. Im trying to print that "hello" onto the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onkeyup` to update the value for every key you press

```js
print = document.getElementById('print');

function printfun(){
    print.innerHTML = document.getElementById('d1').value;
}
```

```html
<div id="print"></div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
   <h3>- Students Name & Age -</h3>
   <input type="number" id="d1" onkeyup="printfun()">
   <button class="button" id="SubmitStudentInformation" onclick="addName()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Thank you